# How to python transitions for robotic applications / embedded systems

Tags: python, transition

I'm looking at using transitions to build state machines for robotic applications. I've previously used simulink stateflow for this kind of task. Here, the state machine can be called periodically and the currently active state is evaluated in order to see if an exit transition can be made to a new state otherwise the current state is maintained (one transition can be made per poll). With this mindset I am attempting an initial toy example with transitions to see if I can get to grips with it but I get the feeling I need to think about this solution differently.

The toy example I thought of is one of those airport automatic passport gates, where the camera translates in Z to match the face height of the user. Here is my (hopefully self describing) attempt:

```
from transitions import Machine
from time import sleep, time
from random import choice

class Passport_cam_sm(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.face_ok = False
        self.height_ok = False

states = ['move2face', 'validate_face', 'open_gate']

transitions = [
    {'trigger': 'at_face', 'source': 'move2face', 'dest': 'validate_face', 'conditions': 'height_ok'},
    {'trigger': 'face_valid', 'source': 'validate_face', 'dest': 'open_gate', 'conditions': 'face_valid'},
    {'trigger': 'face_invalid', 'source': 'validate_face', 'dest': 'move2face'},
]

class Passport_cam(object):

    def __init__(self, terminate_time_s=10, time_step_s=1):

        self.model = Passport_cam_sm()
        self.machine = Machine(model=self.model, states=states, transitions=transitions, initial='move2face', send_event=True)
        self.running = True
        self.init_time = time()
        self.terminate_time_s = terminate_time_s
        self.time_step_s = time_step_s
        self.face_pos_z = 5
        self.camera_pos_z = 0
        self.error_z = 888

    def run(self):
        '''
        main program loop
        :return: 
        '''

        while self.running and not self.main_timeout():

            self.machine.face_ok = self.face_ok()
            self.machine.height_ok = self.height_ok()
            print ('At state ' + self.model.state) #, ' camera height (', self.error_z ,') ok is ', self.machine.height_ok, ' face check is ', self.machine.face_ok)
            # todo - poll latest state here? (self.model.state)
            self.camera_dynamics()
            sleep(1)

    def face_ok(self):
        '''
        very robust method for determining if the face is valid...
        :return: 
        '''
        return choice([True, False])

    def height_ok(self, tol=0.5):
        '''
        Checks if the face height is OK to do comparison.
        :return: 
        '''
        if abs(self.error_z) < tol:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def camera_dynamics(self, max_displacement=1):
        '''
        Moves camera height towards face height at a maximum of "max_displacement" per function call 
        :return: 
        '''
        self.error_z = self.camera_pos_z - self.face_pos_z
        threshold_error = (min(max(self.error_z, -max_displacement), max_displacement))
        self.camera_pos_z = self.camera_pos_z - threshold_error
        print ('Camera height error is: {0}'.format(self.error_z))

    def main_timeout(self):
        if time() > self.init_time + self.terminate_time_s:
            return True
        else:
            return False

pc = Passport_cam()
pc.run()
```

What I expected to find is some way of polling the last state at the 'todo' part in the code to check if any exit conditions are now valid. Is there a way to do this? Re-entering the current state should be OK but I guess some kind of "during" method would be ideal.

Otherwise is there a better way to structure this kind of project and/or are the any example projects like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd suggest to rather 'poll' a transition and wait until it has been conducted successfully. A transition will return `True` when it has been conducted successfully and `False` if a) preparations failed, b) conditions were not met or c) something failed during entering the state or d)issues happening during the processing of `after` events.
I narrowed down your example code to illustrate how this can be used to check whether `face` and `height` had been retrieved successfully:

```
from transitions import Machine
from time import sleep
from random import choice

class Passport_cam_sm(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._face_okay = False
        self._height_okay = False

    def face_ok(self, even_data):
        self._face_okay = choice([True, False])
        return self._face_okay

    def height_ok(self, even_data):
        # tol = even_data.kwargs.pop('tol', 0.5)
        self._height_okay =  choice([True, False])
        return self._height_okay

states = ['move2face', 'validate_face', 'open_gate']

transitions = [
    {'trigger': 'at_face', 'source': 'move2face', 'dest': 'validate_face',
     'conditions': ['height_ok', 'face_ok']},
    {'trigger': 'face_valid', 'source': 'validate_face', 'dest': 'open_gate', 
     'conditions': 'face_valid'},
    {'trigger': 'face_invalid', 'source': 'validate_face', 'dest': 'move2face'},
]


class Passport_cam(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.model = Passport_cam_sm()
        self.machine = Machine(model=self.model, states=states, transitions=transitions,
                               initial='move2face', send_event=True)
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            print('At state ' + self.model.state)
            # model.at_face will only return True when both conditions are met
            while not self.model.at_face():
                print('Checking ...') 
                sleep(1)
            print('Face and height are okay!')
            self.camera_dynamics()
            sleep(1)

    def camera_dynamics(self):
        print("Processing...")
        self.running = False


pc = Passport_cam()
pc.run()
print('Done')
```

I added both checks (face/height_ok) to be conditions for a valid transition.
In case you want to assign them first and only check their values in `conditions` you could make use of the transitions keyword `prepare`.
Functions/methods in prepare will be executed before `conditions` and do not require a boolean return value.
When you specify `send_event=True`, all callbacks should expect that event. This is why `face/height_ok` require the signature used above.
Arguments passed to the trigger event (e.g. `model.at_face(tol=0.5)`) will be assigned to `event_data.args` or `event_data.kwargs`.

Note that I assigned your conditions check to the model. Strings are always assumed to be names of model methods. In case you want to assign functions/methods from somewhere else you can pass references to these functions instead of strings. Also note that this will only work when events are processed instantly. `transitions` supports queued event processing (passing `queued=True` to the `Machine` constructor) which comes in handy when events might trigger other events. When `queued=True` events will *ALWAYS* return true.

**How can polling be done in an agnostic fashion?**

A central feature of a state machine is the ability to adapt its behaviour based on its current state. The same event may result in different results. If you want your machine to constantly poll rather than react to events you can define all transitions to be triggered by the same event:

```
  transitions = [ 
      {'trigger': 'check', 'source': 'move2face', 'dest': 'validate_face',
     'conditions': ['height_ok', 'face_ok']},
      {'trigger': 'check', 'source': 'validate_face', 'dest': 'open_gate', 
     'conditions': 'face_valid'}, # (1)
      {'trigger': 'check', 'source': 'validate_face', 'dest': 'move2face'}, # (2)
  ]
  ...
  # class Passport_cam
  def run(self):
        while self.running:
            print('At state ' + self.model.state)
            while not self.model.check():
                sleep(1)
```

The loop can be simplified to just call `model.check`. This way transitions, checks and states can be introduced without the need to change the polling loop.

Transitions are executed in the order they were added. This means that (1) and (2) form the rule `In state 'validate_face' go to 'open_gate' if 'face_valid', otherwise go to 'move2face'` . Transitions with a source state different from the current state do not have to be checked and do not result in much overhead.

What matters the most is the general design of the machine's states and transitions which is framework independent. If condition checks get bloated, consider splitting states up into smaller functionally more specific states.
You can also split transition configurations and/or compose your model out of several specialised models.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to thoroughly reply. I may have this wrong but the problem I see with polling transitions is that for each state that is added one might have to add new transition polling commands in the Passport_cam.run method. If we added logic for features such as opening & closing of entry & exit gates (for valid/invalid cases), continuous running, person detection, warnings etc. It seems like the logic in Passport_cam.run() could start getting unavoidably complicated? Maybe there are examples of transitions state machines with complicated requirements to prove me wrong?:D

Comment: I added an example where `Passport_cam.run()` is kept as simple as possible and behaviour is exclusively added via state and transition configuration

Comment: Thanks, this polling in an agnostic fashion looks like it will do the trick and good to know that the overhead isn't too significant. Looking forward to further experimenting with the transitions package.